# My cat is afraid of me after bringing him to the vet

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, fear

I tamed a rescue cat, took a long time. He became really loving and friendly after a few months and we became the best of friends.

Yesterday I had to bring him to the vet because he had a cold for a long time, I don't usually agree with vets and human made medicines but he was sneezing for almost a month and it started to concern me.

He was not very happy going there or coming back in the car, and when we got home he just ran away.

Last night he stayed out and only came back this morning for food, but he runs away now when I come close, he lost his trust in me and I am worried it won't come back.

Does anyone know what I can do to regain his trust?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE, maybe you search for questions about regaining the trust of a cat, in the time until your question will be answered. There are some (with other start points) that ask too, how to built up the relationship again :)

Comment: Thank you, actually after a few hours yesterday, after I wrote it, he came into my office and starting purring and was his usual self. Panic over!

Comment: @user19199 I'm so glad to hear that things were better a few hours later. I had a rescue rabbit that avoided me for about half a day after his first vet visit. The stress of traveling and going to the vet can cause that for a lot of different animals. Typically they are back to themselves a few hours later or the next day. If they start refusing to eat for a long period of time than that would be a thing to watch out for/call the vet about.